# Хочу стереть label

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно что бы после того как я нажал отправить,все сообщения до этого стёрлись.Код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
root= Tk()
root.title("Чат - бот")
root.geometry("500x600")

def chat():
    name = ttk.Label(root,text = "Пообщайся с ботом)")
    name.grid(column = 50)
    chatx = Entry(root,width = 40)
    chatx.grid(row = 40,column=10,columnspan = 70)
    ot = ttk.Button(root,text = "Отправить",width = 10,command=lambda: otvet())
    ot.grid(row = 40,column=90,columnspan = 70,)
    def otvet():
        if chatx.get().lower() == "привет":
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: Привет")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)
        if chatx.get().lower() == "ты джеймс!":
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: ты угадал")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)
        if chatx.get().lower() == "выйди за меня":
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: прости,но у меня есть масса других потенциальных женихов")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)
        if chatx.get().lower() == "ты красивая?":
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: Эм")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)
        if chatx.get().lower() == "ты голодная?":
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: Нет,я не сильно то люблю есть...")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)
        if chatx.get().lower() == "что делаешь?":
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: рисую процессор на системном блоке")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)
        if chatx.get().lower() == "как дела?":
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: супер")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)
        else:
            sir = ttk.Label (root, text="Siri: мой словарный запас мал...")
            sir.grid (columnspan=700)

chat()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
root= Tk()
root.title("Чат - бот")
root.geometry("500x600")

def chat():
    name = ttk.Label(root,text = "Пообщайся с ботом)")
    name.grid(column = 50)
    chatx = Entry(root,width = 40)
    chatx.grid(row = 40,column=10,columnspan = 70)
    ot = ttk.Button(root,text = "Отправить",width = 10,command=lambda: otvet())
    ot.grid(row = 40,column=90,columnspan = 70,)
    label = Label(root, text=(""))
    label.grid(columnspan=700)
    def otvet():

        phrase_dict={
            "привет":"Siri: Привет",
            "ты джеймс!":"Siri: ты угадал",
            "выйди за меня":"Siri: прости,но у меня есть масса других потенциальных женихов",
            "ты красивая?":"Siri: Эм",
            "ты голодная?":"Siri: Нет,я не сильно то люблю есть...",
            "что делаешь?":"Siri: рисую процессор на системном блоке",
            "как дела?": "Siri: супер"
        }


        if phrase_dict.get(chatx.get().lower())!=None:
            label["text"]=phrase_dict[chatx.get().lower()]
        else: label["text"]= "Siri: мой словарный запас мал..."


chat()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное,очень помог!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте свойство 'text':

```
sir['text'] = ''
```

Comment: Мне нужно что бы Label стёрся)

Comment: Простите, подправил)

Comment: Нет,это вы меня простите за неправильно поставленный вопрос)

Comment: Если ты тут,можешь помочь с кодом?

Comment: Если тут , то смотри я к примеру написал Привет,бот ответил привет тоже, а потом когда я ей напишу как дела(к примеру), все сообщения до этого пропадут (именно label я про бота ) и появятся новые.

Comment: Я : Привет Siri: привет Я: Как дела?(все сообщения пропадают) Siri:супер(все её сообщения до этого пропадают)