# Нужно стереть Label

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Делаю чат-бота.После каждого сообщения нужно что бы пропадали сообщения бота.Вот пример: "Я:Привет Бот:привет Я:Как дела?(И теперь должны пропадать сообщения бота то есть её label)

```
def chat():
    name = ttk.Label(root,text = "Пообщайся с ботом)")
    name.grid(column = 50)
    chatx = Entry(root,width = 40)
    chatx.grid(row = 40,column=10,columnspan = 70)
    ot = ttk.Button(root,text = "Отправить",width = 10,command=lambda: otvet())
    ot.grid(row = 40,column=90,columnspan = 70,)
    def otvet():
        if chatx.get().lower() == "привет":


            chatx.delete (0, 'end')
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: Привет")

            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)


        if chatx.get().lower() == "ты джеймс!":
            chatx.delete (0, 'end')



            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: ты угадал")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)

        if chatx.get().lower() == "выйди за меня":
            chatx.delete (0, 'end')

            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: прости,но у меня есть масса других потенциальных женихов")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)

        if chatx.get().lower() == "ты красивая?":
            chatx.delete (0, 'end')

            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: Эм")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)

        if chatx.get().lower() == "ты голодная?":



            chatx.delete (0, 'end')
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: Нет,я не сильно то люблю есть...")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)
        if chatx.get().lower() == "что делаешь?":


            chatx.delete (0, 'end')
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: рисую процессор на системном блоке")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)
        if chatx.get().lower() == "как дела?":


            chatx.delete (0, 'end')
            sir = ttk.Label(root,text="Siri: супер")
            sir.grid(columnspan = 700)

        else:


            chatx.delete (0, 'end')
            sirk = ttk.Label (root, text="Siri: мой словарный запас мал...")
            sirk.grid(columnspan=700)
chat()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Чем этот вопрос отличается от предыдущего вашего вопроса?

Comment: Я тебе в прошлой статье написал,посмотри.Тут я задал более конкретный вопрос

Comment: Во-первых не мне, во-вторых стоило тот ответ отредактировать, а не новый создавать.

Comment: Прости,запутался,как редактировать вопросы?

Comment: @Taras: нажмите кнопку [edit]

Comment: Оо привет,не забыл про мой вопрос с django?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Хочу стереть label](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716619/%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%87%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c-label)

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью метода упаковщика - `grid_remove()`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66048/discussion-on-answer-by-personality13---label).